# C++ seekg complexity

Tags: c++

I am storing many objects of different size in a binary file. To allow random access to the file, I was thinking of creating a second file which stores the first (and possibly the end) position of each object. Then, when I need a particular object, I'd look up where it's located and I could use `seekg` to navigate to that position and read it.

My question is, what is the complexity of `seekg`? Is it O(1) or it depends on how far down from the beginning of the file I am setting the position pointer? If it's linear in the position, my solution makes no sense and I could just use some separator between the objects and always read the whole file from the beginning until the separator.

Comment: I say the time is way more dependent on the media used. A hard drive will have seek penalties that you can't control or even know without some OS API.

Comment: Not specified, far as I can tell. Not sure it could be specified, given some of the weird file systems I've seen..

Comment: If the two files are on the same hard disk (SSD is different), the cost of interleaving reads of different files (as the drive head re-positions itself) might overshadow the cost of seeking a location within a file. Or maybe not, if the file is sufficiently fragmented. As with many performance questions, the best approach might be to try it and time it. If the results surprise you, maybe ask for a theoretical explanation of them.

Comment: You need to be aware that usually some caching is done (load whole page from disk) and that alignment/block size might have a major impact on performance. This would be particularly important to consider if your code has a lot of relatively small objects. Access pattern can also have a major impact. Usually you would get best performance if you read from the beginning of a file in block size that is a power of 2 in size (for example 1024 bytes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In binary stream mode, seeking (what `seekg` is) does all the work in filesystem code inside of the kernel (whatever amount of work it does on the C++ side is inconsequential), so if you want to know its computational complexity, you'd need to look at the particular filesystem driver you're using (on Linux it's open source, on Windows you'd need academic access if you're in academia).

But generally speaking, with rudimentary knowledge of how filesystems organize their data: the cost is probably amortized logarithmic or something like that, and you'd need mighty big files to actually measure the computational cost with enough resolution to be able to "see" the logarithmic response (petabyte volumes with a file of similar size on a ramdisk with zero-block compression enabled, so a few gigabytes worth).

In typical scenarios, `seekg` has fixed cost. It spends all the time inside the filesystem driver waiting to pull the few extra blocks with filesystem metadata it needs off the disk. No matter where in the file you seek, it'll need to pull about the same number of new blocks (limiting case of a large file and random seeking). But if you measure the cost in terms of number of blocks read per random seek on a large file, then it's still reasonably enough close to a fixed cost: imagine the largest file you'll have in your application, and for files of that and smaller size, the number of blocks will be bounded by whatever you observed. So as long as you'll be fine with real-world latencies on the largest file you want to deal with, everything else is OK.

Even if `seekg` had O(N) cost, it should not take just as long as reading the file. E.g. on Linux with a wide variety of tape drives, if you open the `/dev/st` device file, seeking has `O(N)` "cost" worst case, but the scaling factor is much better than when reading the file, since tapes seek faster than they read :) And the notion of cost is also weird in all those cases: it's not time spent computing stuff, but time spent waiting for the medium and the head to converge at the right place :)

**Don't forget to open the `fstream` in `std::ios::binary` mode!** If you do forget, `seekg` may well end up having the same cost as reading the file up to that point, and you don't want that.

Comment: Why would opening the file in textmode would make `seekg` expensive?